# How to capture and analyze bluetooth packets using wireshark

Tags: windows-7, wireshark

How would I go about capturing and analyzing bluetooth packets on Win 7  using wireshark ?

I know wireshark can't do "promiscous" capturing of bluetooth packets. I have purchased Ubertooth one for that.

How do I now capture and analyze bluetooth packets?

Answer (score 6):

I may be a little late but whatever.

To capture Bluetooth traffic using Wireshark you will need the BTP software package, you can get it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bluetooth/testing-btp-setup-package). Install the package and find the files (usually it will install in C:\BTP[version]). Find a file named btvs.exe in folder x86. Launch a console with the admin privileges and type `./btvs.exe -Mode Wireshark`. Wireshark windows will launch and start capturing traffic immediately

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Bluetooth page at the Wireshark wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Bluetooth), it looks like on Windows you would have to use a separate tool to capture bluetooth packets. You could then export them in pcap format and open the file in Wireshark.

Alternately, you could install Linux. :)

Comment: As I mentioned I have purchased ubertooth one for "promiscuous" sniffing of bluetooth packets.

I am interested in finding out how to integrate ubertooth one and wireshark in windows

Comment: i can't get the packets still